# How do I install mdbook using Cargo inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker, rust, rust-cargo, mdbook

I am trying to build a Docker container that includes Rust and mdbook. I have tried a number of variations on

```
FROM rust:latest
RUN cargo install mdbook
```

including specifying the exact versions. For example, these don't work work either

```
RUN cargo install --git https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/mdBook.git mdbook
```

and

```
RUN cargo install mdbook --vers "^0.1.0"
```

Things fail when the install gets to compiling lazycell v1.2.0:

```
Compiling lazycell v1.2.0
error: `<core::cell::UnsafeCell<T>>::new` is not yet stable as a const fn
   --> /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/lazycell-1.2.0/src/lib.rs:233:16
    |
233 |         inner: UnsafeCell::new(None),
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = help: in Nightly builds, add `#![feature(const_unsafe_cell_new)]` to the crate attributes to enable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the Rust container from Docker, you can build your own. The version of Rust is still 1.30 (as with `FROM rust:latest`), but for some reason this procedure gets all the dependencies right.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
FROM gcc:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf > rustup.sh
RUN chmod 755 rustup.sh
RUN ./rustup.sh -y
RUN rm /tmp/rustup.sh

RUN ~/.cargo/bin/cargo install mdbook
```